# How to display typespecs from a named function through iex

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex, typespec

You can display typespecs from a module thorugh t command on iex, i.e:

```
iex(1)> t Enum
@type t() :: Enumerable.t()
@type acc() :: any()
@type element() :: any()
@type index() :: integer()
@type default() :: any()
```

But how can I see the typespecs from for example Enum.reverse?

If I go to the source code then I see

```
  @spec reverse(t) :: list
  def reverse(enumerable)
```

Where I suppose `t` stands for Enum itself `@type t() :: Enumerable.t()` and expect to return a `list`

In python for example you can get a method doc through the shell with `??` (python doesnt implement typespecs but you get the idea)

```
In [1]: from urllib2 import urlparse
In [2]: urlparse??
def urlparse(url, scheme='', allow_fragments=True):
    """Parse a URL into 6 components:
    <scheme>://<netloc>/<path>;<params>?<query>#<fragment>
    Return a 6-tuple: (scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment).
    Note that we don't break the components up in smaller bits
    (e.g. netloc is a single string) and we don't expand % escapes."""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IEx.Helpers.h/1` prints the typespec along with the documentation of the function:

```
iex(1)> h Enum.reverse/1

                            def reverse(enumerable)

    @spec reverse(t()) :: list()

Returns a list of elements in enumerable in reverse order.

## Examples

    iex> Enum.reverse([1, 2, 3])
    [3, 2, 1]
```

After a quick read of the `IEx.Helpers` module, I don't think there's a builtin helper function that only prints the typespec of a function.

Edit: `@spec` is not printed in the current stable release of Elixir (1.5.3). This feature [will be present](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/afd51e82d5f443e8aba5932ca3f50d13e828fd7d/CHANGELOG.md#iex) in Elixir 1.6.

Comment: mmm which version of elixir/iex do you use? mine doesnt display the typespec just:
iex(37)> h Enum.reverse/1

                            def reverse(enumerable)                             

Returns a list of elements in enumerable in reverse order.

## Examples

    iex> Enum.reverse([1, 2, 3])
    [3, 2, 1]

Comment: Oh you're right sorry, I was running 1.6-dev. This feature was added in v1.6 which is not released yet. See https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/afd51e82d5f443e8aba5932ca3f50d13e828fd7d/CHANGELOG.md#iex.

Comment: ahh cool, no problem, good feature for 1.6, update answer so people know!

Comment: when you compiled elixir 1.6 did you manage to compile 1.6 mix? mine stays at 1.5.2 bin/mix --version
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Mix 1.5.2
although my elixir is 1.6 Elixir 1.6.0-dev (568ab47) (compiled with OTP 20)

Comment: I use `asdf` to manage multiple Elixir installs as I use Elixir stable in most projects and master only for experiments. Check out https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf and https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-elixir.

Comment: In Elixir v1.10.4 at least, for functions generated by, e.g. `use`-ing another module, the typespec won't be printed by `IEX.Helpers.h/1` if there is no `@doc` attribute generated (even a blank one). `h/1` *does* output the spec for 'regular' functions though even if they don't have docs.